# How to copy string in number format to another sheet?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I'm trying to copy a file from one excel file to another.  **I want to copy the values in the cells (numbers stored as text) to new file as numbers itself**.  How to do it?  I tried Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0" but no luck.  Please help me.

```
 Set myxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    myxl.Visible = True
    Set objWorkbook2 = myxl.Workbooks.Open("C:\C.xlsx")
    Set objWorkbook3 = myxl.Workbooks.Open("C:\PC.xlsx")
    Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook3.Worksheets(1)
    objWorksheet.Activate

    set objworksheet3 = objworkbook2.worksheets.add
    objworksheet3.name="Project_Overview"
    Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets("PC")
    objWorksheet.Activate
    objWorkSheet.Range("A1:A10").Copy
    objWorkSheet2.Paste objWorkSheet2.Range("A1")
    objWorkSheet2.Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0"

    objWorkbook2.Save 
    objWorkbook2.Close

    myxl.Quit
```

Comment: @Jeeped but I want to copy it as a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer the values instead of copying and pasting and set the destination format before the transfer.

```
with objWorkSheet.Range("A1:A10")
    .copy destination:=objWorkSheet2.Range("A1")
    objWorkSheet2.Range("A1").resize(.rows.vount, .columns.count).NumberFormat = "0"
    objWorkSheet2.Range("A1").resize(.rows.vount, .columns.count) = .value2
end with
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It works but how to copy the color formatting?  I tried **objWorkSheet.Range("A1:A10").Copy
objWorkSheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial -4122**  and it works.  However, is there a better method?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a pastespecial; just copy then overwrite the format and values.